# Configure asp.net core application to capture webservice traffic from fiddler

Tags: asp.net-core, fiddler

With ASP.NET following entry on web config help to capture web service call from the asp.net application using fiddler.

```
 <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true">
            <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="False"/>
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
```

With ASP.NET core application how we capture web service call from fiddler.

Answer (score 3):

I found this details from fiddler documentation, for .net core application
https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp#configure-net-core-applications

Use power shell command,
To Add the proxy

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
```

To remove the proxy use the following

```
   netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using RIN library instead potentially. 
https://github.com/mayuki/Rin

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how to configure fiddler to do this